# A java array of objects

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment where I have to create three classes, a client class that performs all I/O, a catalog class that maintains a list of catalogItem objects and a catalogItem class that defines a single item in the store's catalog.

I'm trying to start simple at first and create the array and make sure that it is accepting data before I move on to the rest of the assignment.  I was able to compile it with no issues but when I am trying to display the array, I get nothing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab3
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        Catalog catalog = new Catalog();

        boolean endCatalog = false;
        while (!endCatalog)
        {
            System.out.println("Please choose and option: \n"
            + "1 - Display all items of the catalog\n"
            + "2 - Display an item by keyword\n"
            + "3 - Add an item to the catalog\n"
            + "4 - Remove an item from the catalog\n"
            + "5 - Change the cost of one item in the catalog\n"
            + "6 - Change the cost of all items in catalog by percent\n"
            + "7 - Exit");

            int choice = in.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {
            case 1: System.out.println(catalog.displayAll()); break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Display keyword"); break;
            case 3: System.out.println("Add item:\nEnter ID: ");
                        int newId=in.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Enter description: ");
                        String newDesc=in.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter cost: ");
                        double newCost=in.nextDouble();
                        catalog.add(newId, newDesc, newCost); break;
            case 4: System.out.println("Remove item"); break;
            case 5: System.out.println("Change cost of one item"); break;
            case 6: System.out.println("Change cost by %"); break;
            case 7: endCatalog=true; break; }

        }   
    }
}


class Catalog
{
    final static int MAX = 100;
    private CatalogItem[] catalogItems;
    int inUse;

    public Catalog()
    {
        catalogItems=new CatalogItem[MAX]; 
    }   
    public void add(CatalogItem newItem)
    {
        inUse = 0;
        if(inUse<MAX) {
            catalogItems[inUse] = newItem;
            inUse++; }
    }
    public void add(int newId, String newDesc, double newCost)
    {
        CatalogItem newItem = new CatalogItem(newId, newDesc, newCost);

    }
    /*public void remove(int id)
    {

    }
    public String find(String keyword)
    {

    }
    public void changeCost(int id, double percent)
    {

    }
    public void increaseCost(double percent)
    {

    }
    public String toString()
    {
    }
    public boolean equals(Catalog obj)
    {

    }*/ 

    public String displayAll()
    {
        String str = "";

        for (int i=0; i<inUse; i++) {
            str = str + "\n" + catalogItems[i]; }

        return str;
    }   
}



class CatalogItem
{
    private int itemID;
    private String description;
    private double cost;

    public CatalogItem()
    {
        itemID = 1;
        description = " ";
        cost = 0.0;
    }

    public CatalogItem(int newID, String newDesc, double newCost)
    {
        itemID = newID;
        description = newDesc;
        cost = newCost;
    }

    public int getItemID()
    {
        return itemID;
    }

    public void setItemID(int newID)
    {
        itemID=newID;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String newDesc)
    {
        description=newDesc;
    }

    public double getCost()
    {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(double newCost)
    {
        cost=newCost;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return itemID + ", " + description + ", " + cost;
    }

    public boolean equals(CatalogItem obj)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the problem:

```
public void add(int newId, String newDesc, double newCost)
{
    CatalogItem newItem = new CatalogItem(newId, newDesc, newCost);

}
```

What happens to `newItem` after it is created?

Comment: Yeah I was really confused with the array so I switched over to using an ArrayList.  Now I have...
 
  public Catalog()
  {
    ArrayList <CatalogItem> catalogItems = new ArrayList<CatalogItem>(MAX);
  }  
  public void add(int newId, String newDesc, double newCost)
  {
    CatalogItem newItem = new CatalogItem(newId, newDesc, newCost);  
  }
  public void add(CatalogItem newItem)
  {
    catalogItems.add(newItem);
  }

So newItem is being added to the array.  

I'm still a little confused with accessing the elements of the ArrayList.  How will I manipulate the items if I do it like this?

Comment: Good call on using `ArrayList` rather than a raw array. But there's still a problem: In your `add(int, String double)` method you instantiate a new `CatalogItem` but you don't actually do anything with it. Think about it in pseudocode first: 1) Create a new item 2) Add it to the list. Now make sure your code does that.

Answer (score 1):

There is not items ever added to:

```
private CatalogItem[] catalogItems;
```

That is so, because you call only this method:

```
public void add(int newId, String newDesc, double newCost)
{
    CatalogItem newItem = new CatalogItem(newId, newDesc, newCost);

}
```

And that one will never call method that actually tries to add something to the array:

```
   public void add(CatalogItem newItem)
    {
        inUse = 0;
        if(inUse<MAX) {
            catalogItems[inUse] = newItem;
            inUse++; }
    }
```

In the long run that method will also not work, because item is always added to the index 0. That is so, because as first thing you always set: inUse = 0.

Answer (score 1):

You call this method to add the catalog item:

```
public void add(int newId, String newDesc, double newCost)
{
    CatalogItem newItem = new CatalogItem(newId, newDesc, newCost);

}
```

But as we can see, this doesn't actually do anything with the object it creates. Did you mean to have this overload of `add()` call the other one? That would be a good design.

Also, in the other version of `add()`, you do this:

```
    inUse = 0;
```

Since you reset `inUse` every time `add()` is called, your array will never contain more than one item. Do you see why this is? You should just take this line out.